# Want to change password my login

Tags: password

I want to change my computer's password. Right now my password is abc123. I run this command:

```
sudo passwd
```

I entered my current password and then a new one but the change does not take effect. How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the password of the currently logged in- user, change the password with:

```
passwd
```

not

```
sudo passwd
```

*if* you want to use the command `sudo passwd`, you should tell the shell who's password it is that you want to change:

```
sudo passwd username
```

Answer (score 0):

Your old password is still working, most likely because you did not change it correctly.  You could have answered your own question by reading the man pages: `man man`.  To search for any subject, like passwords, use the k option like this:

```
man -k password
```

This gives you the correct syntax for commands that match the search criteria.  To view the man page for passwd:

```
man passwd
```

To change the password for the account you are logged in as:

```
passwd
abc123
EnterNewPasswordHere
```

Reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-password/

Answer (score 0):

Recently, changing the password with `sudo passwd` on the terminal only updates the password for your current terminal session. To change your password throughout the system permanently:

Run shell as root

```
sudo -i
```

Then change the password in root shell for my account:

```
passwd <username>
```

Remember to exit the root shell after changing the password!